# Deleting lines from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python and here is the problem.

There is a csv file with a bunch of attributes such as "id", "SalePrice", "LotArea" etc. The column with index 3 is the first numeric attribute and the column with index 0 is "id". Also, there are 1460 rows.

Requirement:  Delete a record if its numeric attribute values is an outlier.

My approach:

Step 1. Find Q1, Q2 and IQR

Step 2. Find the id of outliers.

Step 3. Delete the row with outliers.

```
    #Step 1
        index = 0
        outlier_id = []
        data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
        Q1 = data[list(data.columns)[3]].quantile(0.25)
        Q3 = data[list(data.columns)[3]].quantile(0.75)
        IQR = Q3 - Q1
    
    #Step 2
        filter = ((data[list(data.columns)[3]] >= Q1 - 1.5 * IQR) & (data[list(data.columns)[3]] <= Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))
        while(index < 1460):
            if(filter[index] == False):
                outlier_id.append(data[list(data.columns)[0]][index])      #store id of outliers in array
    
            index = index + 1
        print(outlier_id)
    
    #Step 3
        permission = True
        csv_writer =  open('new_train.csv', 'w')

    
        for line in csv_reader:
            index = 0
            while(index < len(outlier_id)):
                if line[0] == outlier_id[index]:
                    permission = False
                index = index + 1
            if(permission == True):
                csv_writer.writerow(line)
        csv_writer.close()
```

I have completed the first 2 steps. The list "outlier_id" contains the id of outliers. I planned to use this list to complete step 3.

The problem comes: there is nothing in the file 'new_train.csv', which I intended to write the rows without outliers.

I cannot find the mistake as I am new to the manipulation of csv files. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: add a debug print after `if(permission == True):` . (BTW - you can change it to `if permission:`

Comment: The step 3 part cannot even compile: `csv_writer` is defined as a plain file object and you try to use it as a `csv.writer`. Anyway, as you have started using pandas, stick to it. Just keep the relevant rows in your dataframe and use `to_csv` on that.

Comment: @SergeBallesta So if csv_writer does not work then what should I put?